# how to change x axis in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to change the scale of x axis in matplotlib in python. I am using following code.

```
df.iloc[:,5:9].plot(kind="density",subplots=True,layout=(2,2),sharex=False)
```

I want to have different X axis scale for all X axis. What I tried is following

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)

ax1.set_xticks(np.arrange(1,5000,500))
ax2.set_xticks(np.arrange(1,5000,500))
ax3.set_xticks(np.arrange(1,5000,500))
ax4.set_xticks(np.arrange(1,5000,500))
```

But, when I run this I get empty figure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate on the axes in which the plots live, not in some newly created empty axes.

```
axes = df.plot(kind="density",subplots=True,layout=(2,2),sharex=False)
axes[0,0].set_xticks(...)
```